# Tree panel in extjs 5 not rendering

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs-mvc, extjs5

The tree panel doesn't get rendered
Code is :

```
Ext.define('mainPanel',{
    extend:'Ext.form.Panel',
    layout: {
    type: 'hbox',
    align: 'stretch'
    },
    width:'100%',
    height:'100%',
    title:'SQL',
    initComponent:function()
    {
        var tableDiv = this.getTableColumn();
        var analyzerDiv = this.getAnalyzerColumn();
        var fieldDiv = this.getfieldColumn();
        this.items=[tableDiv,analyzerDiv,fieldDiv];
        this.callParent();
    },
    getTableColumn:function()
    {   
        var TableColumn = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel',{
                            title:'Tables',
                            width:'20%',
                            heigth:'100%',
                            layout: 'fit',
                            border:true,
                            store: tableTreeStore,
                            rootVisible: false

                        });
        return TableColumn;
    }
```

Pls let me know where i am going wrong. Thanks in advance
the error i get is

TypeError: c is not a constructor
return new c(a[0])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this [Sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/rg2) that i created for you.

This error exists when you are trying to override `initComponent` in default component of Extjs.

For example:

```
Ext.define('Ext.panel.Panel',{
    initComponent: function(){
        //YourCode
    }
});
```

Or

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    initComponent: function(){
        //Yourcode
    }
});
```

If you want eradicate this error from your code you need to for example define your custom `Component - CustomPanel` that extend `Extjs` component:

```
    var panel = Ext.define('CustomPanel', {
                    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
                    width:300,
                    heigth:400,
                    layout: 'fit',
                    initComponent: function(){
                        var tableDiv = this.getTableColumn();
                        this.items=[tableDiv];
                        this.callParent();
                    },
                getTableColumn:function() {   
                   return Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel',{
                   title:'Tables',
                   width:300,
                   heigth:400,
                   layout: 'fit',
                   border:true,
                   store: tableTreeStore,
                   rootVisible: false
               });
          }
    });
```

And somewhere in your code - creation of `CustomPanel`:

```
    Ext.create('CustomPanel', {       
    });
```

Hope this is something that you were looking for.

Comment: I appreciate your help Pawel, I would like to know what is wrong in my code because I have rendered other components like grid, fieldset etc with the initComponent.

Comment: hard luck ! I have already used a custom panel. I am editing the code in my post @Pawel

Comment: Hard luck in what case ? It is working or not ? The same error appears ? Fiddle that i provide is working with your use case. Maybe there is a problem with your code overall ? Post please a code that is working as intended with your initComponent.

Comment: Thanks Pawal for inducing a thought that the other part of the code may have the error. you are correct! Now I have identified and fixed the mistake in other part of the code.

Comment: Put in comment here what was wrong and mark as answered. Lets make this clear for others.

Comment: sure ! I am adding a grid component to the main item and there was an error in the grid . I wanted a grid to be editable and also have drag and drop property . I made a mistake by giving to pluggins like,
    
    ptype: ['cellediting','gridviewdragdrop'],

Comment: Alright great that we made progress and finished that case. Cheers.